# Sublime Text 2 Ruby console not working

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

The following code:

```
p ({ table: 2, sandwich: "hamburger", drink: "cola" })
```

gives the following output in a normal terminal session with `ruby _filename_.rb`:

```
{:table=>2, :sandwich=>"hamburger", :drink=>"cola"}
```

and in the console of Sublime Text 2 using Command+b:

```
/Users/*******/Desktop/scratchpad.rb:1: odd number list for Hash
p ({ table: 2, sandwich: "hamburger", drink: "cola" })
           ^
/Users/*******/Desktop/scratchpad.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
p ({ table: 2, sandwich: "hamburger", drink: "cola" })
           ^
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Sublime Text might be running a Ruby version from before the `foo: "bar"` Hash syntax was introduced (perhaps the OS X default Ruby).

You can verify this by running a script in Sublime Text with

```
p RUBY_VERSION
```

It should output a version 1.9 or newer.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Now, I must change the Ruby version sublime is using: http://upstre.am/blog/2011/07/sublime-text-2-with-rvm-on-osx/